# Como guardar valor inserido pelo utilizador em 2 arrays diferentes?

Tags: c, array

Boas, este código faz parte da tentativa de resolução de um exercício. O meu objectivo é converter todos os valores de Kelvin para Celcius ou vice-versa e apresentar todos os valores inseridos pelo utilizador sejam eles valores de temperatura em Celcius ou Kelvin. Para isso já criei 2 arrays onde guardo o valor inserido . 
O problema é no output os valores passam posições á frente . Print do output: [output](https://prnt.sc/lxp4cn).
 Ex : Inserindo 3 temperaturas em Celcius no output apareçe no lugar 0,1,2 e depois se inserirmos temperatura em Kelvin essas vão começar a apareçer na posição 3 em vez de começarem de novo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float CalculaC(float tK);
float CalculaK(float tC);
void ShowResults(float storesC[], float storesK[], int elementNumbers);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
float tC, tK, storesC[11], storesK[11], calC, calK;
int i,j;
char var;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("Insert 10 temperatures values and identify it as Celsius or Kelvin with K or C respectively:");
    scanf("%f", &tC);

    var = getchar();

    if(var == 'C' || var == 'c')
    {
        storesC[i] = tC;
        calK = CalculaC(storesC[i]);
        printf("value: %f \n",calK); // this is just for testing if the function was working    
    }
    else if(var == 'K' || var == 'k')
    {
        storesK[i] = tC;
        calC = CalculaK(storesK[i]);
        printf("value: %f \n",calC);    // this is just for testing if the function was working 
    }
}
ShowResults(storesC,storesK,i);

getchar(); 
}

float CalculaC(float tK)
{
float temp;
temp = tK - 273.15;

return temp;
}

float CalculaK(float tC)
{
float temp;
temp = tC + 273.15;
return temp;
}

void ShowResults(float storesC[], float storesK[], int elementNumbers)
{
int j,z;
for(j = 1; j < elementNumbers; j++ )
{
    printf("Value in Celcius: %f \n", storesC[j]);
}

for(z = 1; z < elementNumbers; z++ )
{
    printf("Value in Kelvin: %f \n", storesK[z]);
}   
}
```

Comment: Como você coloca as temperaturas em um ou outro array, dependendo da unidade de temperatura, mas com a variação do mesmo índice para os 2 arrays então você terá ausência de dado em um ou outro array.  Creio que seria melhor você controlar os índices separadamente para cada um dos arrays (creio que seria este o objetivo dada a utilização do parâmetro elementNumbers.

Comment: @anonimo Certo e como seria possível controlar os indices separadamente?Tenho de criar 1 Loop FOR antes de cada "IF" para cada temperatura ficando assim com 2 Loops FOR ?

Answer (score 0):

Falta duas variaveis de controle, uma para a quantidade de itens inseridos no array de C, e outra pro array de kelvin. Tente assim:

```
float tC, tK, storesC[11], storesK[11], calC, calK;
int i,j, countC = 0, countK = 0;//Contador para Celsius e Kelvin

char var;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("Insert 10 temperatures values and identify it as Celsius or Kelvin with K or C respectively:");
    scanf("%f", &tC);

    var = getchar();

    if(var == 'C' || var == 'c')
    {
        storesC[countC] = tC;
        calK = CalculaC(storesC[countC]);
        countC++;
        printf("value: %f \n",calK); // this is just for testing if the function was working    
    }
    else if(var == 'K' || var == 'k')
    {
        storesK[countK] = tC;
        calC = CalculaK(storesK[countK]);
        countK++;
        printf("value: %f \n",calC);    // this is just for testing if the function was working 
    }
}
```

e em ShowResults:

```
void ShowResults(float storesC[], float storesK[], int countC, int countK)
{
    int j,z;

    for(j = 1; j < countC; j++ )
    {
        printf("Value in Celcius: %f \n", storesC[j]);
    }

    for(z = 1; z < countK; z++ )
    {
        printf("Value in Kelvin: %f \n", storesK[z]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado , resultou perfeitamente ! Nunca tinha pensado nessa alternativa e estava complicar tentando de outras formas sem ser necessário . Mais uma vez agradeço pela ajuda .